# Matrix calculation using gpu

Tags: python, c++, matrix

Today i was asking to me if is possible to do matrix calculation using gpu instead cpu because i know that a gpu is designed to do them faster then a cpu.
I searched on the net and i found notices about the matrix calculation using gpu with different python's libraries but my question is exists a documentation that descibes how should we write code to comunicate with a gpu.
I'm asking that  because i want to develop my own one to better understand how gpu work and to try something different. 
Thanks to all.

Comment: You should definitely have a look at CUDA documentation to understand how data can be transferred from CPU to GPU and then start learning more abstract libraries to hide all the boilerplate and perform just the *matrix multiplication*.

Comment: An alternative could also be OpenCL, which also works if you are not running on NVIDIA hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that problem with OpenCL

OpenCL is a standard library that the vendor of the GPU's implement by their own. Like NVIDIA support openCL and other features thanks to CUDA library.

Here a good [guide to get start](https://anteru.net/blog/2012/11/03/2009/index.html)